# Integer programming books

Tags: integer-programming, books

I would like to know which books are best to study integer programming. I can see similar questions on this website, such as this one:
[Books for integer and mixed integer programming](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/8333/books-for-integer-and-mixed-integer-programming)

Integer and Combinatorial Optimization by Nemhauser and Wolsey is one of the recommended books. I am trying to determine whether it is worth getting this book, but I prefer something which is not too heavy with proofs or math symbols.  This book was published in 1988 so it will not cover any recent developments. Is this book highly regarded because it provides loads of examples or any material that is not found in the other books?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Books for integer and mixed integer programming](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/8333/books-for-integer-and-mixed-integer-programming)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are good reference books for introduction to operations research?](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/870/51), that answer, to be specific.

Comment: @JorisKinable I have viewed these questions and have referenced one of them in my post. I want to specifically know about this book “ Integer and Combinatorial Optimization by Nemhauser and Wolsey”. So some one who has read it should be able to advice whether it is good to read or it is well outdated now.   It is one of the highly recommended books for integer programming based on search results, so there must be a reason for it.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least three somewhat distinct aspects to integer programming: theory (e.g., why LP solutions occur at vertices of polytopes); algorithms (branch-and-bound, decomposition, cutting plane generation ...); and modeling (turning a problem into a solvable model, pros and cons of "big M", ...). Recommended books are likely to be stronger in some aspects than others, so it might help to know which aspect(s) concern you the most.

For model building, I like "Model Building in Mathematical Programming" by H. P. Williams and "Applications of Optimization with Xpress" (with the caveat that when I went shopping for optimization books, Gutenberg was still refining the details of his printing press).

Comment: I have the H.P. Williams book and it is really good. I am interested in books that cover algorithms as some problems may not be outright solvable unless some special techniques such as cutting planes, etc. are used. I don't know whether books covering these algorithms will also cover some integer programming theory to understand the methods.